# tx_news get fluid image src to use for background image

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

In the tx_news plugin list partial, I want to change the image it generates into a background image.

```
<f:image image="{mediaElement}" title="{mediaElement.originalResource.title}" alt="{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}" maxWidth="{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}" maxHeight="{settings.list.media.image.maxHeight}"/>
```

How to I get the `src` of the image so I can put it into an inline style?

Comment: Here you can see documentation about `f:uri.image` : https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ImageViewHelper.html

Comment: @ravisachaniya thank you, I am having trouble getting the variables to work eg. `{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}` within the `f:uri.image` any advice?

Comment: @RaviSachaniya typo3 documentation is useless garbage.

Comment: @user2879055 if you have any good useful TYPO3 documentation, then please share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the f:uri.image Viewhelper and use the same  attributes.
Your code will look like this:
`{f:uri.image(image:mediaElement,title:'{mediaElement.originalResource.title}',alt:'{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}', maxWidth:'{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}',maxHeight:'{settings.list.media.image.maxHeight}')}`

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the variables eg `{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}`

Comment: `{f:uri.image(image:mediaElement,title: mediaElement.originalResource.title, alt: mediaElement.originalResource.alternative, maxWidth: settings.list.media.image.maxWidth, maxHeight: settings.list.media.image.maxHeight)}`

No need for the quotes

Answer (score 2):

Use the URI viewhelper

```
{f:uri.image(image: mediaElement)}
```

Comment: Ok, great. How can I get the resized image rather than the uploaded size?

Comment: `{f:uri.image(image: mediaElement, width: settings.x.y)}`

Comment: How can I insert `{settings.list.media.image.maxWidth}` into the maxWidth instead of a number?